# Kendo visible binding does not work with data-align property?

Tags: data-binding, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I've just encountered something weird with data binding in kendo-ui.

```
<div data-role="view" data-title="hi" data-model="viewmodel">  
    <div data-role="header">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <div data-role="view-title"></div>
            <span data-bind="visible: visible">
                <span data-align="right" data-role="button">edit</span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  

<script>  
    var viewmodel = kendo.observable({
        visible: true
    });    
    var app = new kendo.mobile.Application();  
</script>
```

I've set up a DOJO example to illustrate the bug I've encountered. [DOJO EXAMPLE](http://dojo.telerik.com/Ifiti/14)

As you can see the `visible` property in my `viewmodel` is set to `false`. This means, according to the binding I've set, it should hide the button. But whether I set the `visible` flag to `true` or `false`, the button always shows. (Re-run the snippet when you've changed the visible flag)

But then I tried to remove/add properties to check what 'blocks' the visible binding. I found out it was the button property `data-align="right"` that was 'blocking' the visible binding.

You can see in this [example](http://dojo.telerik.com/Ifiti/15) (where I removed the `data-align` property from the button) that when you change the `visible` flag in my `viewmodel` to `true` or `false` it actually hides/shows the button based on `visible` flag.

Does anyone know this bug and/or has a workaround/solution for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that you are binding on a span element with a nested span inside it, containing a button.

Both spans have a data binding, but you're setting the aligment on the button only; this should be set to the outer container like so:

```html
<!-- add the data-align on this outer 'container' element -->
<span data-align="right" data-bind="visible: visible">
    <!-- ... and not on the element below here... -->
    <button data-role="button">edit</button>
</span>
```

I've also cloned and updated [your dojo example here](http://dojo.telerik.com/EmAvi).